# import subfolder in python

Tags: python, import, subdirectory

I have folder structure as follows:

```
/foo/trunk/mss/cloud
```

and

```
/foo/trunk/mss/model
```

my python file is located at subfolder model with name test.py I want to import all modules located in subfolder cloud so my code in test.py is:

```
import mss.cloud as cloud
```

but I got an error:

> ImportError: No module named mss.clould

should I make any change on PYTHONPATH or anything else? any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A way to achieve it is to add the relative path to `sys.path`, for example:

```
$ find .
.
./cloud
./cloud/foo.py
./model
./model/t.py


$ cat cloud/foo.py
print 'greetings from', __name__

$ cat model/t.py 
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'cloud'))    
import foo

$ python model/t.py 
greetings from foo
```

Comment: is there any way that I just change PYTHONPATH?

Comment: sure: `export PYTHONPATH=$(cd ../cloud && pwd):$PYTHONPATH`